# "No SDK found at specified location" error in Monodevelop

Tags: sdk, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I installed Mac OS X version 10.8.2.

After that, I either installed Monodevelop first or XCode first. But when I got this error, I deleted both. Then, installed XCode 4.5.2 and then installed MonoDevelop again, but it was using an older SDK.

So I copied the `iPhoneOS6.0.sdk` from the

```
  Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

folder and put it into a separate folder on my machine

```
  /SDKs/
```

Then I set the path in MonoDevelop to use the SDK as found in /SDKs folder. But I am still getting this error-

```
"No SDK found at specified location"
```

This is very frustrating. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of this should be required. MonoDevelop should automatically find the SDK.

- Try leaving the SDK location empty so MD will say "using default location".
- If you want to point it to a specific SDK, let it point to the Xcode.app file. An app file is nothing but a folder. MonoDevelop will find the SDK in there. No need to copy anything.

Comment: Thanks for the "leaving the SDK location empty" suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

First do **not** copy files/directory around. Mostly because this is **not** needed but also because you might break your installation(s) and get hard to diagnose bugs.

MonoDevelop's Apple SDK location (in the preferences) must point to the `Xcode.app`, which by default, is `/Applications/Xcode.app` (that's where MonoDevelop will look for if nothing is specified).

You can point it elsewhere, e.g. `/Volumes/Xcode/XcodeXX-DPX.app` if you want to mount a disk image with a specific version of Xcode.

Notes:

- when MonoDevelop finds what's it's looking for then you'll get a green checkmark (so you know it's properly configured);
- you might have to run Xcode first so it will install it's command-line tools and device support libraries. Without them it's possible the the builds/installation will fail (but with a different error message than the one you mentioned)